# Calling all database table names to create a list || pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, django, database, pyodbc

I currently have an MSSQL server that has about 60 databases in it.

Does anyone know a way to list the database names with a for loop, so that I am able to access each table?

The structure should be something like this :

```
for each Database in Server    
  MyList{} = MyList + DatabaseName    
endfor
```

I can't seem to find any documentation that includes something like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the `sys` tables in order to get all the objects in your server.

In order to get all the databases, run the following query:

```
SELECT name, database_id FROM sys.databases
```